# Laravel 5 named route with parameter

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm pretty new on laravel5 and I'm trying to generate dynamically route alias under route.php

This is it:

```
Route::get('/menu/{category}/{product}/{item}', 'MenuController@listItem')->name('/{category}/{item}');
```

I already tried with with 'as' and 'uses' and I'm still getting:

```
/menu/{category}/{product}/{item}
```

With all parameters replaced by the correct values instead of:

```
/{category}/{item}
```

Comment: Sorry I tried to put hi but it looks doesn't want to update, bf someone shoot me :D

Comment: What's your purpose ?

Comment: the purpose is just replace the url displayed for example :'http://localhost:8080/menu/homme/bijoux/pendentif" by "http://localhost:8080/homme/pendentif" where homme is {category} and pendentif is {item]

Comment: Why do you not create another route for this ? Then MenuController@listItem will accept 2 parameters are {category} and {item}.

Comment: Hi I have difficulty to filter the parameters given and redirect it to the right controller. in the same page I have differents actions using url with only 2 parameters for example {{ url('/facebook/follow') }} or {{ url('/pinterest/follow') }} or {{ url('/enfant/jouet') }} etc... So I decide to add some fix parameters to help me in route.php to identify the action. Hope is not too confused

Comment: Why ? You had "pendentif" is the item, do you have any problem while get result from database ?

Comment: no I m building an ecommerce pendentif is just a product and homme is gender

Comment: You should look again your logic. I will forget this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? I think your question is somewhat vague.

Answer (score 7):

Expounding on what Vinicius Luiz said.

```
Route::get('/menu/{category}/{product}/{item}', ['as' => 'named.route' , 'uses' => 'MenuController@listItem']);

// to get the actual linke
route('named.route', ['category' => $category->id, 'product' => $product->id, 'item' => $item->id]);
```

depending, you may not do ->id or anything, you might just pass the whole $category, $product, etc. Depends on how the routing in your controllers is setup.

EDIT:
From your comment, it likes like you want something like:

```
class MenuController {
    public function lisItem($category_name, $product_name) {
        $category = Category::where('name', $category_name)->first(['id']);
        $product = Product::where('category_id', $category->id)->where('name', $product_name')->first();
    }
}

Route::get('/{category}/{item}', ['as' => 'named.route' , 'uses' => 'MenuController@listItem']);

// to get the actual linke
route('named.route', ['category' => $category->id, 'item' => $item->id]);
```

there is probably a better way to do the queries, but that should work for you.

Comment: Hi Kenyon thx for your reply but you lost me I though my question was simple I just want replace the displayed URL by another using the given parameter as shown in the example. Is it possible or not?

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to accomplish? Doing what I gave you, you would end up with a URL like `/menu/10/5/6` which would resolve to `MenuController@listItem` when viewed. Are you trying to alias a route? Or are you trying to have the URL show different? What do you actually want the URL to be?

Comment: exaclty I just want the displayed url is different of what is used to route to take your example I just want to see /10/6

Comment: If you want to use ids instead of names, then just change the controller method so something like `listItem($category_id, $product_id)` and the query would be something like `$product = Product::where('category_id', $category_id)->where('id', $product_id')->first()`

Comment: Though, you in theory should have unique IDs for your data, so even if you wanted to keep the extra parameter in the URL, you could just not use it, and do something like `$product = Product::findOrFail($product_id)`

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
Route::get('/menu/{category}/{product}/{item}', ['as' => 'a.name.to.your.route' , 'uses' => 'MenuController@listItem']);
```

Comment: Try expanding on your answer, as to what you did to fix the problem.

Comment: Hi Luiz thanks same result looks like as is not used